Unable to import pjsua2 - Undefined symbol: pj_log_5
I'm trying to compile pjsua2 from source, but receive this error when I to import the library in python 3.12 after building it:
Python 3.12.1 (main, Dec 18 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20231205 (Red Hat 13.2.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pjsua2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/pjproject-2.14.1/pjsip-apps/src/swig/python/pjsua2.py", line 12, in <module>
    import _pjsua2
ImportError: /pjproject-2.14.1/third_party/lib/libspeex.so.2: undefined symbol: pj_log_5

Here is how I am compiling:
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
./configure
make dep && make
sudo make install
cd pjsip-apps/src/swig/python
make
sudo make install

What am I missing?

Download the Master repo version, not the release~
There is a bug with 2.14.1 and it has been fixed in the Master repo.
Version 2.14.1 also doesnt properly support python threading, the Master does
I learned this by having issues myself, learning that there are some fundamental changes in python 3.12

distutils package have been completely removed and replaced by setuptools, so setup.py will be running into issues, those have been fixed in the master repo.

You don't have to install the entire pjsip library, you just have to do make dep && make, this builds the library that setup.py needs in order to compile the python module with swig, remember to check for errors when running ./configure and when running make dep && make.

make sure to make the necessary changes/make the config_site.h file, it is a very important step, as the documentation say's, if you aren't sure what needs to go in there, you can do a #include<config_site_sample.h>, which needs to be done in project root/pjlib/include/pj, do a make realclean and re-run make dep && make to rebuild with the new parameters.

Make sure to have run either make python in the swig folder, it needs to regenerate the pjsua2_wrapped.cpp file for every new build/compile of the main project. do a make realclean to wipe any residue data, and run either make python or manually run swig with the following command.

swig -doxygen -I../../../pjsip/include -I../../../pjlib/include -I../../../pjlib-util/include -I../../../pjmedia/include -I../../../pjnath/include -c++ -w312 -threads -python -o python/pjsua2_wrap.cpp pjsua2.i this will rebuild it, and add code comments to python code, however swig for some reason makes it into a Java docstring, which i have made a solution for to convert to python code comments. see My solution for the fix, simply add it to the python folder and run the code to transform the pjsua2 file.

Ensure you have all the necessary packages for python3 aswell, such as dev packages, having the latest SWIG version installed, I found out that there are a few issues with the make function, so i ended up digging deep into the necessary requirement needed to run it properly. See the bug report that follows the steps to get a working version running.


Once you have done all these steps, it should compile and install for you when you run python3 -m pip install . or if you have a virtual environment active pip install .. the latter version installing directly into the virtual environment, vs the first one that will install it into your /home/username/.local/lib/python3.x instead.
I have supplied a pull request on their repo with solutions to the swig/python, and have been working on it for a few months now
Hope this helps you, as well as others that may have issues with getting python up and running with pjsua2
